# Making webservice

Tags: java, web-services, oracle-adf

I have written the following Java code to write a web service which will return some rows from a database table:

```
package ncw;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.jws.Oneway;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class PLSQLWS {
    @WebMethod
    @Oneway
    public ArrayList getSalesPlanningTestData() {
        String query = "select * from sales_planning_test_data";
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Connection conn = connect();
            if (conn != null) {
                PreparedStatement stmt =  conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    SALES_PLANNING_WS_DATA row = new SALES_PLANNING_WS_DATA();
                    row.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                    row.setPoNumber(rs.getString(2));
                    row.setSomethingElse(rs.getString(3));
                    row.setFlag(rs.getString(4));
                    data.add(row);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return data;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNames(){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("usman");
        list.add("Mohsin");
        return list;
    }

    private Connection connect() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection connection =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.xxx.x.xxx:1531:mysid", "username","password");
        return connection;
    }
}
```

**SALES_PLANNING_WS_DATA.java**

```
package ncw;



public class SALES_PLANNING_WS_DATA {
    private int id;
    private String poNumber;
    private String somethingElse;
    private String flag;

    public SALES_PLANNING_WS_DATA() {

    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setPoNumber(String poNumber) {
        this.poNumber = poNumber;
    }

    public String getPoNumber() {
        return poNumber;
    }


    public void setSomethingElse(String somethingElse) {
        this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
    }

    public String getSomethingElse() {
        return somethingElse;
    }

    public void setFlag(String flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }


    public String getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return getPoNumber();
    }
}
```

I create  webservice using JDeveloper. When I test it in HTTP Analyzer and call getSalesPlanningTestData() method, I am not getting any results. Output section says "The selected message is not soap message". When I call getNames() method, it return me the data.

Do anyone know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@Oneway` annotation. It defines the webmethod having not return any data

Comment: @usman The question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057794/understanding-oneway-annotation-in-jax-ws