# Spring boot apache CXF capture soap errors and return http error code

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, cxf, java-ws

I am using spring boot with Apache CXF.   The starter im using is the spring boot `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws`.  I followed the guides from apaches cxf own website. `http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html`.

I am also using Java11.

The problem I'm having is that soap requests into the application that error always return 200 headers regardless if there was an error or not.

The web service endpoint I'm hitting is a void method but I would still like to return a 500 code in the http header if it doesn't work.

The strategy I have in mind is to create an interceptor that will intercept soap requests that error and modify the final response with a http header code.  So the body would be null for void methods but the header is 400 or 500.

**My soap service configuration looks like this**

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class WebServiceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new SoapEventEndpoint());
        endpoint.publish("/EventEndpoint");
        endpoint.setWsdlLocation("ReceiveEvent.wsdl");

        // this interceptor works
        endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(soapInterceptor());

        // these two fault interceptors do not work!
        endpoint.getInFaultInterceptors().add(soapFaultInterceptor());
        endpoint.getOutFaultInterceptors().add(soapFaultInterceptor());

        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractSoapInterceptor soapFaultInterceptor(){
        return new SoapFaultInterceptor( Phase.PRE_STREAM);
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractSoapInterceptor soapInterceptor(){
        return new SoapInterceptor( Phase.PRE_STREAM);
    }
}
```

**Interceptors**

```
@Slf4j
public class SoapFaultInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    public SoapFaultInterceptor(String phase) {
        super(phase);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        log.info("THIS NEVER GETS CALLED!!  Execpting errors to invoke this method");
    }
}

@Slf4j
public class SoapInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {


    public SoapInterceptor(String p){
        super(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        log.info("THIS WORKS");
    }
}
```

**WSDL to Java Generated event endpoint**

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "xyz", name = "ReceiveEventEndpoint")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface ReceiveEventEndpoint {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "ReceiveEvent", action = "xyz")
    @Oneway
    public void receiveEvent(
        @WebParam(partName = "in", name = "ReceiveEventRequest", targetNamespace = "xyz")
        ReceiveEventRequest in
    );
}
```

**1)  When I invalidate with the XML and send the request.  Only the  `SoapInterceptor` intercepts it?   The `SoapFaultInterceptor` doesnt? Any suggestions?**

```
Interceptor for {http://xyz/}SoapEventEndpointService#{http:/xyz}ReceiveEvent has thrown exception, unwinding now

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://xyz", local:"EventId1"). Expected elements are <{http://xyz}LocalAssessmentId>,<{http://xyz}LOTId>,<{http://xyz}EventId>,<{http://xyz}Benefit> 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:938) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:744) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:172) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:194) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[cxf-core-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: null
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:483) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:417) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:394) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:887) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$200(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:103) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$3.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:926) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:924) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: unexpected element (uri:"xyz", local:"EventId1"). Expected elements are <{http://xyz}LocalAssessmentId>,<{http://xyz}LOTId>,<{http://xyz}EventId>,<{http://xyz}Benefit>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:744) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:262) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:257) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:124) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.childElement(Loader.java:105) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.childElement(StructureLoader.java:268) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:574) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:246) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:180) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:415) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:2.3.1]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://uxyz", local:"EventId1"). Expected elements are <{http://xyz}LocalAssessmentId>,<{http://xyz}LOTId>,<{http://xyz}EventId>,<{http://uxyz}Benefit>
    ... 68 common frames omitted

2019-03-27 15:44:15.245 DEBUG 22552 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.t.http.AbstractHTTPDestination     : Finished servicing http request on thread: Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
2019-03-27 15:44:15.245 DEBUG 22552 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.t.servlet.ServletController        : Finished servicing http request on thread: Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-4,5,main]
```

**2) How do I add an interceptor (or fault listener) or some other method to update the http header after errors are intercepted?

Comment: Can you try overriding handleFault()?

Comment: good shout... I tried that and it hasnt worked

Comment: So part one now works..  I just needed to add the handleFault like you suggested.  However it needed to be injected before the marshal phase not after it...  Guess next challange to figure out is how to add a http header

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```
@Override
public void handleFault(Message message) {
    Map<String, List> headers = (Map<String, List>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
    try {
        headers.put("Status", "500");
        ...
    } catch (Exception ce) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ReceiveEventEndpoint` interface the method `receiveEvent` is annotated with the [`@OneWay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jws/Oneway.html) annotation that means it has only an input message and no output (including Faults).

You can find more details here [Understanding @Oneway annotation in JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057794/understanding-oneway-annotation-in-jax-ws), http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Detecting-unmarshalling-error-with-Oneway-operations-td5742536.html, and http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/OneWay-interpretation-and-HTTP-binding-td5711719.html

For debugging reasons if you need to throw Faults in OneWay operations, you can add the [Message.ROBUST_ONEWAY](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/Message.html#ROBUST_ONEWAY) property to your endpoint:

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new SoapEventEndpoint());
    endpoint.publish("/EventEndpoint");
    endpoint.setWsdlLocation("ReceiveEvent.wsdl");

    // interceptors...

    //To throw exceptions in OneWay messages
    Map<String, Object> prop = new HashMap<>();
    prop.put(Message.ROBUST_ONEWAY, true);
    endpoint.setProperties(prop);

    return endpoint;
}
```

For invalid requests, you will get an HTTP 500 with the following body without the necessity to add a custom interceptor:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://xyz", local:"EventId1")...</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score -2):

The following worked for me: in the class `package-info.java` in project, I changed:

```
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED
```